# I can't figure out how to update data with triggers

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE TABLE fav_sports 
(
    ID int,
    sport varchar(20)
);

CREATE TABLE try_outs 
(
    ID int
);

CREATE TRIGGER players 
BEFORE INSERT ON fav_sports 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO try_outs VALUES(NEW.ID);
END;
```

Whenever I try to update "try_outs" with the "players" trigger, I get an error - "SQL statement ignored" and "column not allowed here".

Please help.

The program throws errors when creating this trigger.

Comment: Couple of things. 1) Please edit the post and tag the specific database platform. 2) Please include your insert statement. 3) It's a good habit to always explicitly list out the columns in an insert statement. It will save you time and frustration down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small syntax error. Change:

```
NEW.ID
```

to:

```
:NEW.ID
```

So the full line looks like:

```
INSERT INTO try_outs VALUES(:NEW.ID);
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5bd2a/1).